# data mining: Frequent Item sets

Tags: data-mining

When asked in an exam question to find all frequent Item sets is it just the set that was last worked out that is the answer you give or is it necessary to give all before that too.

e.g. say if last results i get for a set is (A,B,D) then is that my frequent item set or do I need to also include all found before that that also satisfy minSup e.g. (A,B) (A,D) (B,D) etc

Comment: What do you mean by 'exam question,' and what does this question have to do with programming?

Comment: Nothing specifically to do with programming but it related to data mining

Comment: Your question is more suited for cross-validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks I will re ask question here!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're asking if a frequent item set satisfies minimum support threshold, is the subsets of this item set also supports minimum support? The answer is **Yes** the subsets also satisfies the minimum support threshold.

The logic in here is the bottom-up approach. The size 2 candidate itemsets are generated from size 1 frequent itemsets. The size 3 candidate itemsets are generated from size 2 frequent itemsets.

For an example data set:

- Row 1 : A B C D E
- Row 2 : A C D
- Row 3 : B C
- Row 4 : A C D E
- Row 5 : A D E
- Row 6 : A B C D
- Row 7 : A B C
- Row 8 : A C
- Row 9 : B C D
- Row 10: B D E

First the size 1 candidate itemsets were generated. These are: A, B, C, D, E. Now support of each candidate were calculated. A=7, B=6, C=8, D=7, E=4. Now if the minSup value is 5 E is pruned. İf minSup value is 3 then all size 1 candidates were evaluated as frequent.

Second size 2 candidate itemsets were generated. The approach is to cross-product size 1 frequent itemsets. So A B, A C, A D, A E, B C, B D, B E, C D, C E, D E size 2 candidate  itemsets were generated. After this the support values of each candidate were calculated. Support for A B is 3 since Row 1, Row 6 and Row 7 includes this pattern. But B E candidate is present for only Row 1 and Row 10 and if the minSup value is 3, this candidate is pruned.

Because this logic is used, if the upper itemset is frequent, the subsets should also be frequent. If not the upper itemset couldn't be generated.

I hope I could explain myself.